# Location of the system-wide file table and inode table structures in the kernel source

Tags: linux, kernel, file-descriptors, source-code

1. To better understanding of the file management in Linux kernel I want to find out three table declarations in the source:

   - a single process file descriptor table
   - system-wide table of open files
   - inode table

   At this moment I have found only **a single process file table**, which is declared in [include/linux/fdtable.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/03fb3acae4be8a6b680ffedb220a8b6c07260b40/include/linux/fdtable.h#L48) and used inside the process's structure `task_struct`: [include/linux/sched.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/03fb3acae4be8a6b680ffedb220a8b6c07260b40/include/linux/sched.h#L919)

   From Wikipedia [File descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor#Overview):

   [image]
2. Is there a way to look in the content of **system-wide table of open files**
   from the user space? The **single process file descriptor table** can be viewed by `ls -l /proc/PID/fd` command for example.